# converting matlab "find" to "numpy" where

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm trying to convert some matlab code to python code with the numpy lib.
The code search in arrays values and save the found indexes

the original matlabcode

```
index1 = find(array1 == 2 & array2 > array3);
```

my python "translation"

```
index1 = np.where((array1 == 2) & (array2 > array3))
```

is this the correct way?
I can't test the output because I have no matlab, I hope someone can help me with that. Thanks!

Comment: Test it on a test array and see if it does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
np.nonzero( np.logical_and( array1 == 2, array2 > array3 ) )
```

You can read more about [`logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) and [`nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html). You might also consider replacing `nonzero()` with [`flatnonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html)